# Is it possible to use a reverse range in global search

Tags: global-command

I have an error report where often the known errors are in the top few thousand lines, formatting issue rather than quantity unfortunately.

I want to run `:g/pattern/` from the end of the file.

I know `:g/pattern/m0` reverses the file which is mainly the same thing but if I don't put it back to how it was the line references are wrong when I query the error.

I tried `$,1g/pattern/` but got `Backwards range given, Ok to swap (y/n)?`.

Selecting n aborts the command.

Is this achievable?

Comment: Do you need to act on the lines? Or just search?

Comment: @Steve, I think you could be more specific about *why* you need to process the file from the bottom up. Right now, it's hard to tell what exactly is your motivation...

Comment: Hi @filbranden 
I have a very large file with multiple `**error lines` per physical error. When there is a defect impacting the report I often miss the trees for the forest.
Reversing the search is just a way of filtering out most of the errors at the top of the file and ensuring I don't miss some.

`:g/pattern/m0` works but I was hoping to use a reverse range

Comment: @Steve Are you just searching? If so, why not `?pattern`, which will search backwards? Why are you using `:g`? To *search* for those lines? Using `/` and `?` are the search operators, and the latter searches backwards... Are you using the pattern to look for the lines with the error? Perhaps some form of folding might help you, folding all lines that are not the ones you care about... But it's still hard to figure out *exactly* what you want. Can you give more specific examples? Perhaps a snippet of a file and the operation you're trying to accomplish there? Please edit the question.

Comment: Use `?` to search backwards or reverse the file first `:%!tac`

Comment: /doh I'd been using `:g` to get a list of the error and just forgot ? did what I want

Comment: @Steve Don't worry, Vim has so many commands that it's often hard to remember or find exactly what we're looking for. That's why having Vi&Vim.SE is so awesome. I just turned this into an answer, since it seems to have solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest idea is to filter

```
:v/pattern/d
```

And then `u`ndo when you want the whole file back.

Comment: Aside: known errors is a huge red flag.

Comment: More there is a config issue causing false positives. When the config is finished they should/will go away

Answer (score 1):

Use [`?`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%3F) to search backwards.

If [`'wrapscan'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wrapscan%27) is set (which is the default), you can use `?` at the start of the file, and it will wrap to the end and continue the search from there, effectively finding the last occurrence of the pattern in the file.

From there, you can use the [`n`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#n) command, repeatedly, to jump to the preceding occurrences.

This should allow you to easily find the lines containing a specific pattern at the end of a log file such as the one you describe.