# Is it possible to do a reverse vimdiff

Tags: vimdiff

There are many answers like [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20900/is-it-possible-to-use-a-reverse-range-in-global-search) which talk about reversing the search results in one vimbuffer.

But I am wondering if there is way to highlight matching lines only in vimdiff. Something like following: `vimdiff --reverse file1 file2` and the outcome highlights matching lines and hides non-matching.

Comment: not out of the box. you can probably script something around `diff_hlID()` and fold away lines that have diff highlighting applied to it. Something like this: `:windo :set foldminlines=0 fdm=manual diffopt-=filler|:g/^/if diff_hlID(line('.'),1)|:norm! zf|endif`. However that will create single line folds even for consecutive lines, so there is room for improvements.